# ... que j'en ai fait - faite

Tags: accord

**Contexte du texte**

J'ai un paragraphe qui explique un concept : une vue. Ce concept est donc au féminin singulier.

Mon second paragraphe donc un exemple d'utilisation, j'ai donc la phrase :

> Une des utilisations que j’en ai **fait** a été de [...]

**Question**

Le mot **fait** est il bien accordé ? En langage parlé, **fait** *sonne* le mieux et serait donc invariable mais j'ai quand même une hésitation. Peut-être faut-il l'accorder au féminin.

> Une des utilisations que j’en ai **faite** a été de [...]

**Sources**

D'après [francaisfacile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-27694.php) et [lefigaro](http://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/expressions-francaises/2017/11/22/37003-20171122ARTFIG00007-j-en-ai-faite-ne-faites-plus-la-faute.php) l'accord se ferait avec ce qui se trouve avant le **que**, c'est à dire "Une des utilisations" donc au féminin singulier.
D'après le correcteur de Word, ce serait "faites" donc accordé uniquement avec "utilisations"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il faut écrire *faite* car une utilisation est dénombrable et le COD est **que** qui renvoie à ***une** des...*, pas le pronom *en* qui peut être retiré de la phrase :

> Une des utilisations que j'ai faite à été de...
>
> Une des utilisations que j'en ai faite à été de...

Une autre source qui confirme celles déjà fournies : [Aidenet](http://www.aidenet.eu/conjugaison44.htm)

Comment: Intéressant, mais pour être honnête je ne comprend pas bien, plus de détails seraient les bienvenus.

Comment: @Ced Dans ton exemple, on ne peut pas retirer *en* qui est essentiel à la phrase. *En* est donc le COD. *Des erreurs, j'ai fait* n'est pas acceptable. Dans le phrase de la question, on peut au contraire supprimer *en* sans changer le sens de la phrase. *En* n'est donc pas le COD mais un pronom accessoire, l'accord se fait avec *que*.

Comment: Merci pour la réponse et pour la source additionnelle

Comment: Merci pour les explications !

Answer (score 1):

Les deux possibilités sont correctes ; si le contexte est que plusieurs utilisations  existent, celles-ci étant au préalable connues par d'autres personnes  mais que seulement une a été faite par la personne qui parle, alors on utilise « faite » et on défini par ce choix « que j'en ai faite » comme complément du groupe nominal « une des utilisations » ; sinon les utilisations sont le fait de la personne qui parle, c'est à dire qu'elle a eu recours à plusieurs utilisations et on utilise « faites », ce qui force la définition de  « que j'en ai faites » en tant que complément du noyau « utilisations » (sous noyau  et noyau du groupe nominal « utilisations que j'en ai faites ».

On voit cela dans un exemple qui comprend deux concepts au lieu d'un (utilisation) ;

- la révision des devoirs que j'ai faite (*J'ai fait une révision des devoirs de quelqu'un*)
- la révision des devoirs que j'ai faits (*J'ai fait les devoirs, quelqu'un d'autre a fait une révision ou personne ne l'a faite.*)

Answer (score 0):

Oui le mot fait est bien accordé ici, il faut donc dire:

> Une des utilisations que j’en ai **fait** a été de [...]

Le participe passé étant invariable.

Lorsque «**en**» est le COD d'un participe passé conjugué avec le verbe «**avoir**» et qu'il le précède, le participe passé est généralement **invariable**.»

Exemple:

> «Des erreurs, j'en ai fait.»

La préposition reprend ici le mot «erreurs», «en» ne peut être ôtée de la phrase. Il n'y a donc pas d'accord. [Source](http://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/expressions-francaises/2017/11/22/37003-20171122ARTFIG00007-j-en-ai-faite-ne-faites-plus-la-faute.php)

Comment: Merci de la réponse. Les sources sont-elles donc fausses ou ma phrase est très spécifique et est donc une "exception" ?

Comment: Je viens d'ajouter des détails à ma réponse ainsi qu'une source: «lorsque «en» est le COD d'un participe passé conjugué avec le verbe «avoir» et qu'il le précède, le participe passé est généralement invariable.

Comment: C'est la même source que j'utilise dans la question, et il y est dit qu'il y a des exceptions lors de l'utilisation du "que"

Comment: Voir la réponse de @jiliagre, il semble que oui :)